# How to pass dependencies for JSR-269 processor to maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, annotations, compilation, slf4j, processor

I have a JSR-269 annotation processor that I am attempting to invoke from within a Maven build using the maven-compiler-plugin. The processor has a dependency on the SLF4J library, but I cannot figure out how to pass it properly to the compiler plugin so the processor can find it. AS a consequence I am getting the standard SLF4J error when it cannot find a logging binding.

Currently my plugin definition looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>com.mycompany.MyProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <proc>only</proc>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding slf4j as normal project dependency instead as plug-in dependency should work in your set-up. Alternatively you could use the [Maven Annotation Plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) which allows to specify annotation processors (and their dependencies) as plug-in dependency.